# Move files from assets in android studio

Tags: android, assets, move

I have a file in the assets folder. I need to move one file of them to a folder say /emulated/0/download as an example. I want to do this when I click a button then the file must be moved. How do I do it?

Comment: Get an `AssetManager` from a `Context`. Call `open()` on the `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on the asset. Copy the bytes to where you want them.

Comment: iam sorry but can you please write the command iam new in androidstudio i hope you understand me

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/v4file/FilesCPDemo.java#L35-L46) and [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/v4file/FilesCPDemo.java#L58-L69).